# Have jsff page modal window from another subsytem

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a jsff page inside subsystem A. I have another jsff page inside of subsystem B. I have a button inside of the page inside of subsystem A  which I would like to open a modal window which inside would be the jsff page from subsystem B. How can I do this? I am using jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0

Comment: What do you mean by subsystem in your question ?

Comment: @Sid a subsystem workspace. http://www.vesterli.com/2013/09/03/adf-architecture-made-simple-small-medium-large/

Answer (score 1):

Package B as an ADF library that is added into A.
Then in A you can use a popup with a region in it showing the task flow from the B library.